# How to "use" ZFS native encryption on ubuntu 19.10

Tags: encryption, zfs

Just an end user here.
I read a lot about new ZFS support and native encryption. But when install Ubuntu 19.10 with ZFS, they provided no option for encrypt the disk.

How can I enable it, or my disk already encrypted (not really understand what native encryption mean, is it mean all of my data encrypted by default)?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the encryption code hasn't been released by the current copyright owner, Oracle, so it doesn't appear in any free implementation of ZFS.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS#Encryption for more detail.

As noted there, GELI can be used to the same effect if you're running BSD but that's not entirely relevant here.

Comment: The link you posted has updated information. The encryption paragraph states, "As of 2019 the encryption feature is also fully integrated into OpenZFS 0.8.0 available for Debian and Ubuntu Linux distributions." Obviously it'll take some time for Canonical to bring in the encryption to Ubuntu.

Comment: I just tested zfs encryption on Ubuntu 20.04. It works, but it is 4x slower than LUKS. So if you are low on CPU power, LUKS will work faster.